# изменение положение блока

Tags: javascript

Хотелось бы что бы сайдбар прилипал к верху как только прячется "верх" сайдабара , а сейчас получается когда мы доходим до низа сайдбара

код:

```
var change = document.getElementById('sidebar');

var SourceBottom = change.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + window.pageYOffset;

window.onscroll = function() {
    if (change.classList.contains('fixed') && window.pageYOffset < SourceBottom) {
        change.classList.remove('fixed');
    } else if (window.pageYOffset > SourceBottom) {
        change.classList.add('fixed');
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dirkdirk/ugcpv9pg/27/

Comment: а что такое _avatarElem_? вы его используете в коде, но нигде не определяете

Comment: пордон, то старое обозначеные было , исправил

Comment: не забудьте обновить ссылку на jsfiddle

Comment: ну он у вас и прилипает к верху

Comment: действительно ) и на том спасибо)

Comment: так в чем заключается ваш вопрос? в чем вы видите ошибку?

Comment: хотелось бы что бы сайдбар прилипал к верху как только прячется "верх" сайдабара , а сейчас получается когда мы доходим до низа сайдбара

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34299/discussion-between-grundy-and-dirk).

Answer (score 1):

Вот таким образом решилось

```
var change = document.getElementById('sidebar');
var top = document.getElementById('top');
var SourceBottom = top.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
    if (change.classList.contains('fixed') && window.pageYOffset < SourceBottom) {
        change.classList.remove('fixed');
    } else if (window.pageYOffset > SourceBottom) {
        change.classList.add('fixed');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var change = document.getElementById('sidebar');

var SourceTop = change.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;

window.onscroll = function() {
    if (change.classList.contains('fixed') && window.pageYOffset < SourceTop) {
        change.classList.remove('fixed');
    } else if (window.pageYOffset > SourceTop) {
        change.classList.add('fixed');
    }
};
```

```css
.top{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background:black;  
}

#sidebar{
  width:50px;
  background:blue;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 0;  
}
.content{
  float:right;
  height:4000px;
  width:80%;
  background:red;
}
.fixed {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```